# simulate user identity in web.config

Tags: asp.net

I have an intranet. I want to test my security but I cant create account in ldap. instead I want to simulate the connected user in web.config. 
It's just changing/customize the HttpContext.User.Identity.Name.

Comment: set the application to use Windows Integrated Auth and then sign in.

Comment: I want to "sign" as a dummy user that I dont know the password. I'm already windows integrated, but I only log as myself. I want to test as somebody else.

Comment: You cannot fake sign in as someone else